# Checking login data with foreach?

Tags: php, authentication, foreach

I am busy with improving my PHP skills and making a simple login script. I check the $accounts array with a foreach loop, but think I am doing something wrong because without the breaks the script gives the error for each wrong account login. I only don't know what I need to use instead of the foreach. Can somebody help me with this?

Simple HTML Form:

```
<form method="post">

    <label>E-mail:</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" />

    <label>Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" />

    <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" />

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php $accounts = array(

        1 => array(
            'surname' => 'Matt',
            'lastname' => 'Kent',
            'email' => 'matt@email.com',
            'password' => 'test123'

        ),
        2 => array(
            'surname' => 'Jake',
            'lastname' => 'Johnssen',
            'email' => 'jake@email.com',
            'password' => 'test456'
        )
    );

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

        foreach($accounts as $account) { 

            if($account['email'] == $_POST['email'] && $account['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
                echo 'You are logged in!';
                break;  
            }
            elseif($account['email'] != $_POST['email']) {
                echo 'Wrong e-mail';
                break;
            }
            elseif($account['password'] != $_POST['password']) {
                echo 'Wrong password';
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: no need of break. It's not switch case. then why are you having your data in array? if it is coming from db, then you can check in query itself.

Comment: foreach will loop through the array regardless of it is correct or not. So as you have 2 arrays one is always going to be false. Also using an array of passwords is not very good practice. Especially for passwords that haven't been hashed (using salt) it seems very insecure. Are you not able to use a database using either the PDO extension with prepared statements or MySQLi with prepared statements

Comment: @kumar_v Okay, but I used break because otherwise the script gives an error for every account, wrong login combination

Comment: I'm curious. Why the `foreach` method for allowing multiple accounts to login? Isn't just the one ample? @Robbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I want to log in as user2 (Jake Johnssen). The foreach will however will start with user1 (Matt Kent) and because `$account['email'] != $_POST['email']` I will get the `Fout e-mail adres` error and the foreach will `break`.

You can do it like the following

```
$emailFound = FALSE;
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    if ($account['email'] == $_POST['email']) {
        if ($account['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
            echo 'successful login!';
        } else {
            echo 'wrong password';
        }
        $emailFound = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if ($emailFound === FALSE) {
    echo 'wrong email';
}
```

- you have a flag `$emailFound` which lets you know whether the email was in the defined array or not
- it will only check password if the emails match, so it doesn't check Jake's password against Matt's (as in the case mentioned above).

This assumes that one email cannot be held by two users, so once the correct email was found, you can `break` the loop as the following users aren't of interest anymore.

---

Case1: I want to login as user2 with an incorrect password. The foreach will go something like this

1. iteration: `if ($account['email'] == $_POST['email'])` returns false, so no further check
2. iteration: `if ($account['email'] == $_POST['email'])` returns true, so go inside

   - `if ($account['password'] == $_POST['password'])` returns false, so go in else
   - show error and `break` as we are finished

As you can see it works. This is because in your current script, there won't ever be a 2nd iteration, as you always `break` (one of those `elseif`s is most likely true).

Comment: Okay thanks for you answer! So foreach is the right choice to do this job?

Comment: I wouldn't call it the "right choice". Yes, you can do it like this and if you'll always have less than a handful of users, you won't get into that serious problems. But is there a specific reason you don't use a database for this? They were designed exactly for jobs like this and querying a database will be much more efficient and easy (once you know how) than writing your own script to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes I want to use a database but because this was a quick try for me to make the login a used the arrays but now I am gonna watch some sql tutorials.

Comment: Ok, have fun - once you know a little about it, it should be quite easy - also I think the [official manual](http://www.php.net) has some good snippets for each method. Do yourself a favour and don't start using `mysql_*` functions but `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead!

Comment: Thanks for you help! What's the difference between them?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a place for a discussion/chat like this. There are many good resources out in the web, I'm sure you'll find something that helps you